# Developing a new app using facebook friends list

Tags: facebook

I am looking at developing an app that will make use of Facebook and have a question. In order for the app to work it would need to not only access the user's friends list, but also the user's friends' friends list and beyond. It would only access the users who have also signed up to the app.
Thanks in advance
Samy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And your question is …? :-) If you want to know if it’s possible to get that information – well, as long as the friends have authorized your app, there should be no problem, even over several „levels” of friends.

Comment: Sorry after all that I forgot to ask the question ! Yes that's correct, thanks for the answer.